# How to get data from Oracle SQL dump

Tags: mysql, oracle, import

I have a .sql file (text file containing SQL statements for creating tables and inserting data)  that is apprently dumped from an Oracle database.

I want the data (or at least some of it) imported into a MySQL database. The normal import doesn't work because of some specific datatypes.

What should I do? My guesses:

1. Somehow create an Oracle database, import the dump, then make SQL requests to pull the data out. If so, do I have to buy the thing? And do I have to make a separate virtual machine for the Oracle database?
2. Find and replace Oracle-specific stuff to something that MySQL understands. If so, are there any standard ways to translate things like `VARCHAR2`?

Comment: `.sql` does not give us any information as to the data contained within it. You might as well have said "I have a .txt file" for all the use it is. What kind of information is contained in the file? Please update your question to include an example of the file contents. I ask because your usage of the word "dump" implies that the contents were created via an export or a datapump export (expdp), but the rest of your question implies otherwise.

Comment: @Boneist sorry, I edited. It contains SQL statements. I didn't specify that because in my experience every database dump into SQL format has been such file containing plain text SQL statements that recreates the database structure and inserts data into it.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you can *translate* Oracle to MySQL. Here is a reference page: [Oracle to MySQL Migration - SQLines](http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-mysql).

In my case I had to translate things like `NUMBER(13,0)` to `BIGINT` and `NUMBER(12,2)` to `DECIMAL(12,2)`.

What wasn't explicitly stated in the big table (but mentioned lower) was that Oracle syntax specifies units for the size of varchar. So I translated `VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE)` to `VARCHAR(4000)`.

In my file the `to_timestamp` function was used. The table of built-in functions did not say what to do, but I replaced it with `str_to_date` as the result was written to a `DATETIME` field.

I also had microseconds which were excluded from the `to_date` [reference on SQLines](http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-mysql/to_date). At the end of the day `to_timestamp('01-JAN-00 12.00.13.130000000 AM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM')` becomes `str_to_date('01-JAN-00 12.00.13.130000000','%d-%b-%y %h.%i.%s.%f')`.